# Upload to Azure Media Services / blob storage with SasLocator not showing uploaded file

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-mobile-services

So I want to upload video's from client desktop application to Azure Media Services (which of course uses Azure Storage).

I am trying to do a combination of:

- this old documentation: [3 - Uploading Video into Microsoft Azure Media Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/dn735908(v%3Dpandp.10))
- and this relative new documentation: [Upload multiple files with Media Services .NET SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/previous/media-services-dotnet-upload-files#upload-multiple-files-with-media-services-net-sdk).

The first one shows an perfect example of my scenario, but the second one illustrates how to use `BlobTransferClient` to upload multiple files and have a "progress" indicator.

The problem: It does seem to upload and I don't get any error after uploading, yet nothing is showing up in Azure portal / Storage account.
It seems to upload because task takes long, task manager shows wifi upload progress and Azure storage shows that (successful) requests are being made.

So, serverside, I create a SasLocator for a temporary time:

```
public async Task<VideoUploadModel> GetSasLocator(string filename)
{

    var assetName = filename + DateTime.UtcNow;

    IAsset asset = await _context.Assets.CreateAsync(assetName, AssetCreationOptions.None, CancellationToken.None);

    IAccessPolicy accessPolicy = _context.AccessPolicies.Create(assetName, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10),
        AccessPermissions.Write);

    var locator = _context.Locators.CreateLocator(LocatorType.Sas, asset, accessPolicy);

    var blobUri = new UriBuilder(locator.Path);
    blobUri.Path += "/" + filename;

    var model = new VideoUploadModel()
    {
        Filename = filename,
        AssetName = assetName,
        SasLocator = blobUri.Uri.AbsoluteUri,
        AssetId = asset.Id
    };
    return model;
}
```

And client-side, I try to upload:

```
public async Task UploadVideoFileToBlobStorage(string[] files, string sasLocator, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var blobUri = new Uri(sasLocator);
    var sasCredentials = new StorageCredentials(blobUri.Query);

    //var blob = new CloudBlockBlob(new Uri(blobUri.GetComponents(UriComponents.SchemeAndServer | UriComponents.Path, UriFormat.UriEscaped)), sasCredentials);
    var blobClient = new CloudBlobClient(new Uri(blobUri.GetComponents(UriComponents.SchemeAndServer | UriComponents.Path, UriFormat.UriEscaped)), sasCredentials);
    var blobTransferClient = new BlobTransferClient(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1))
    {
        NumberOfConcurrentTransfers = 2,
        ParallelTransferThreadCount = 2
    };
    //register events
    blobTransferClient.TransferProgressChanged += BlobTransferClient_TransferProgressChanged;
    //files
    var uploadTasks = new List<Task>();
    foreach (var filePath in files)
    {
        await blobTransferClient.UploadBlob(blobUri, filePath, new FileEncryption(), cancellationToken, blobClient, new NoRetry());
    }



    //StorageFile storageFile = null;

    //if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(file.FutureAccessToken))
    //{
    //    storageFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(file.Path).AsTask(cancellationToken);
    //}
    //else
    //{
    //    storageFile = await StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.GetFileAsync(file.FutureAccessToken).AsTask(cancellationToken);
    //}
    //cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    //await blob.UploadFromFileAsync(storageFile);
}
```

I know I am probably not doing it correctly with naming of assets and using the progress indicator instead of await, but of course I first want this to work first before finishing it.

I configured Azure Media Services to "Connect to Media Services API with service principal", where I created a new Azure AD app and generated keys for that, like [this documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/previous/media-services-portal-get-started-with-aad). I am not really sure how this exactly works, little unexperienced in Azure AD and Azure AD apps (guidance?).

Uploading:

[image: uploading of asset]

Asset created but no files:

[image: media services]

Storage doesn't show any files either:

[image: blob containers]

Storage does show successful upload:

[image: statistics]

The reason I can't exactly follow the [Upload multiple files with Media Services .NET SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/previous/media-services-dotnet-upload-files#upload-multiple-files-with-media-services-net-sdk) documentation is because it uses the `_context` (which is `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MediaServices.Client.CloudMediaContext`), that `_context` I can use serverside but not client-side because it requires the TentantDomain,RESTAPI Endpoint, ClientId and Client Secret.

I guess uploading via SaSLocator is the correct way (?).

**UPDATE 1**

When uploading using `CloudBlockBlob` it does upload again and it is shown in my storage account within an asset, yet when I go the media services within azure and click on the particular asset, it doesn't show any files.

So the code for that:

```
var blob = new CloudBlockBlob(new Uri(blobUri.GetComponents(UriComponents.SchemeAndServer | UriComponents.Path, UriFormat.UriEscaped)), sasCredentials);
//files
var uploadTasks = new List<Task>();
foreach (var filePath in files)
{
    await blob.UploadFromFileAsync(filePath, CancellationToken.None);
}
```

I've also tried to upload an asset manually within Azure. So Clicking on "Upload" in the Asset menu, then Encoding it. This all works fine.

**UPDATE 2:**

Digging deeper I came up with the following, not yet production-proof, way to make it currently work:

**1.** Get a Shared access signature directly from storage and upload it to there:

```
public static async Task<string> GetMediaSasLocator(string filename)
{
    CloudBlobContainer cont = await GetMediaContainerAsync();
    SharedAccessBlobPolicy policy = new SharedAccessBlobPolicy()
    {
        SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(60),
        Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Write,
        SharedAccessStartTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-5)
    };
    await cont.FetchAttributesAsync();

    return cont.Uri.AbsoluteUri + "/" + filename + cont.GetSharedAccessSignature(policy);
}
```

With this SaS I can upload just like I showed in UPDATE 1, nothing changed there.

**2.** Create a Azure Function (which was already planned to do) which handles the asset creation, file uploading to asset, encoding and publishing.
This has been done by following this tutorial: [Azure Functions Tools for Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-develop-vs#check-your-tools-version) and then implement the code that is illustrated in [Upload multiple files with Media Services .NET SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/previous/media-services-dotnet-upload-files#upload-multiple-files-with-media-services-net-sdk).

So this "works" but is not perfect yet, I still don't have my progress indicator within my client WPF application and the Azure Function takes quite a long time to complete because we basically "upload" the file again to an Asset after it is already in Azure Storage. I rather use a method to either copy from one container to an asset container.

I came to this point because Azure functions need a fixed given container name, since assets create their own containers within an storage account, you can't trigger an Azure function on those. So to work with Azure Functions it seems I really have to upload it to a fixed container name and thereafter do the rest.

**Question still remains:** Why uploading a video file to Azure Storage via the `BlobTransferClient` does not work? And if it will work, how do I trigger an Azure function based on multiple containers. A 'path' like asset-{name}/{name}.avi would be preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually it turned out that I need to specify the **base URL** in the `UploadBlob` method, so without the filename itself which is within the SasLocator URL, but only the container name.

Once I fixed that I also noted it didn't upload to the filename I have provided in the SasLocator I generated server side (it includes a customerID prefix). I had to use one of the other method overloads to get the correct filename.

```
public async Task UploadVideoFilesToBlobStorage(List<VideoUploadModel> videos, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var blobTransferClient = new BlobTransferClient();
    //register events
    blobTransferClient.TransferProgressChanged += BlobTransferClient_TransferProgressChanged;
    //files
    _videoCount = _videoCountLeft = videos.Count;
    foreach (var video in videos)
    {
        var blobUri = new Uri(video.SasLocator);
        //create the sasCredentials
        var sasCredentials = new StorageCredentials(blobUri.Query);
        //get the URL without sasCredentials, so only path and filename.
        var blobUriBaseFile = new Uri(blobUri.GetComponents(UriComponents.SchemeAndServer | UriComponents.Path,
            UriFormat.UriEscaped));
        //get the URL without filename (needed for BlobTransferClient (seems to me like a issue)
        var blobUriBase = new Uri(blobUriBaseFile.AbsoluteUri.Replace("/"+video.Filename, ""));

        var blobClient = new CloudBlobClient(blobUriBaseFile, sasCredentials);
        //upload using stream, other overload of UploadBlob forces to put online filename of local filename
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(video.FilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        {
            await blobTransferClient.UploadBlob(blobUriBase, video.Filename, fs, null, cancellationToken, blobClient, 
                new NoRetry(), "video/x-msvideo");
        }
        _videoCountLeft -= 1;
    }

    blobTransferClient.TransferProgressChanged -= BlobTransferClient_TransferProgressChanged;
}

private void BlobTransferClient_TransferProgressChanged(object sender, BlobTransferProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("progress, seconds remaining:" + e.TimeRemaining.Seconds);
    double bytesTransfered = e.BytesTransferred;
    double bytesTotal = e.TotalBytesToTransfer;
    double thisProcent = bytesTransfered / bytesTotal;
    double procent = thisProcent;
    //devide by video amount
    int videosUploaded = _videoCount - _videoCountLeft;
    if (_videoCountLeft > 0)
    {
        procent = (thisProcent + videosUploaded) / _videoCount;
    }

    procent = procent * 100;//to real %
    UploadProgressChangedEvent?.Invoke((int)procent, videosUploaded, _videoCount);
}
```

Actually `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MediaServices.Client.BlobTransferClient` should be able to do concurrent uploads but there is no Method for uploading multiple yet it has properties for `NumberOfConcurrentTransfers` and `ParallelTransferThreadCount`, not sure how to use this.

I didn't check if this is now working with Assets as well because I now upload to 1 single container for every file and later using an Azure Function to process to an Asset, mainly because I can't trigger an Azure Function on a dynamic container name (every asset creates its own container).